# Two WHILE inside a function - Not getting one executed

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-6

I am trying to add the result of two DB_QUERY inside a function one after one by help of WHILE, but getting result one only one WHILE when I am downloading CSV, where I am printing the final variable. Here is the code -

```
    <?php

function getPaidScoutUsers($nid) {
  $csv_output = '';
  $all_paid_scouts_entry = db_query("SELECT * FROM {signup_event} WHERE event_nid = %d",$nid);
  while($paid_user = db_fetch_object($all_paid_scouts_entry)){
    $role_name     = 'Scout';
    $profile       = content_profile_load(scout_profile, $paid_user->attendee_uid);
    $firstname     = $profile->field_sfname[0]['value'];
    $lname         = $profile->field_last_name[0]['value'];
    $patrol        = get_term_name($profile->field_scout_patrol[0]['value']);
    $position      = get_term_name($profile->field_scout_rank[0]['value']);    
    $homephone     = "";
    $cellphone     = "";
    $email         = "";
    $paid_status   = 'Paid';
    $payment_date  = date_format_date($paid_user->created_date[0]['value'],$type = 'custom', $format = 'm/d/Y');
    $csv_output .= "\"".$role_name."\"".","."\"".$lname ."\"".","."\"".$firstname."\"".","."\"".$patrol."\"".","."\"".$position."\"".","."\"".$homephone."\"".",".$cellphone.",".$email.","."\"".$paid_status."\"".","."\"".$payment_date."\""."\r";    
  }
  return $csv_output;
}

function getUnpaidUsers($nid) {
    $csv_output = '';
    $all_unpaid_scout_list = db_query("SELECT * FROM users
                                     INNER JOIN users_roles ON users.uid = users_roles.uid
                                     WHERE users_roles.rid =7
                                     AND users.uid NOT IN (
                                     SELECT attendee_uid FROM signup_event WHERE event_nid = %d)
                                     ORDER BY name ASC",$nid);
    while($unpaid_user = db_fetch_object($all_unpaid_scout_list)){
      $role_name     = 'Scout';
      $profile       = content_profile_load(scout_profile, $unpaid_user->uid);
      $firstname     = $profile->field_sfname[0]['value'];
      $lname         = $profile->field_last_name[0]['value'];
      $patrol        = get_term_name($profile->field_scout_patrol[0]['value']);
      $position      = get_term_name($profile->field_scout_rank[0]['value']);   
      $homephone     = trim($profile->home_phone[0]['value']);
      $cellphone     = trim($profile->cell_phone[0]['value']);
      $email         = $profile->email_1;
      $paid_status   = 'Unpaid';
      $payment_date  = '';
      $csv_output .= "\"".$role_name."\"".","."\"".$lname ."\"".","."\"".$firstname."\"".","."\"".$patrol."\"".","."\"".$position."\"".","."\"".$homephone."\"".",".$cellphone.",".$email.","."\"".$paid_status."\"".","."\"".$payment_date."\""."\r";
    }
    return $csv_output;
}

function event_signup_download_detail($nid)
{ 
    //global $user;   
    module_load_include('inc', 'signup_event', 'event_signup_view');
    $csv_output = '';
    $csv_output .= "Role,Last name,First Name,Patrol,Position,Home phone,Cell Phone,Email,Payment Status,Payment Date\n";           
    $nid = 2001;

    // add the paid users to the csv 
    $csv_output .= getPaidScoutUsers($nid);

    // get unpaid users, add them to the csv
    //$csv_output .= getUnpaidUsers($nid);

    echo $csv_output;

    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;   filename=\"Registration_Dues_Information.csv\"");
    print $csv_output;
    exit; 

}
```

Where I am wrong in this ? Can anybody help ?

Comment: Does echo $csv_output show the correct result?

Comment: can you add var_dump(db_fetch_object($all_paid_scouts_entry)); before entering the while loop? Does it return an array of objects?

Comment: I can't tell which database interface you're using here, but many interfaces only keep one resource handle active at a time. So it could be the case that making two `db_query` calls one after the other is essentially throwing one away. Which query is getting added and which is not showing up? Try moving the second `db_query` call after the first while loop.

Comment: @PatrickM - I did try after I saw your comment...but same result

Comment: @Stephen - It gives : bool(false)

Comment: @RajeevK  Try and paste the tresult here. echo  $all_unpaid_scout_list; echo $all_paid_scouts_entry;

Comment: @RajeevK Place $all_paid_scouts_entry = db_query("SELECT * FROM {signup_event} WHERE event_nid = %d",$nid); above the second while loop and run the file to check $CSV_output.

Comment: what does var_dump($all_paid_scouts_entry) return? It seems that either your query isn't being executed properly by the database adapter.

Comment: Also try adding $nid = (int)$nid; under global $user;

Comment: @HarmeetKaur - I have edited the code in question now. You can see that, my first WHILE is for PAID user & so that I am putting query of UNPAID before second loop...but same result

Comment: What result does this give?  echo $all_unpaid_scout_list; echo $all_paid_scouts_entry; Getting mysql result resources or not ?

Comment: @Stephen - It gives : object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(26) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Comment: See my last comment about adding the (int), it will let me know if i solved your issue.

Comment: @Stephen - If same $nid is working for one query, it should work for another one too. But still I tried with same result..

Comment: @HarmeetKaur - Both echo is not giving any result..

Comment: @RajeevK is the first or second one not being executed?

Comment: @RajeevK ok. one wild  guess. change variable names in the second while like change  $role_name to  $role_name1 and run the code.

Comment: I agree with Harmeet on this one, try naming all variables within the same scope uniquely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try splitting the functionality into seperate methods.

```
function getPaidScoutUsers($nid) {

  $csv_output = '';
  $all_paid_scouts_entry = db_query("SELECT * FROM {signup_event} WHERE event_nid = %d",$nid);
  while($paid_user = db_fetch_object($all_paid_scouts_entry)){
    $role_name     = 'Scout';
    $profile       = content_profile_load(scout_profile, $paid_user->attendee_uid);
    $firstname     = $profile->field_sfname[0]['value'];
    $lname         = $profile->field_last_name[0]['value'];
    $patrol        = get_term_name($profile->field_scout_patrol[0]['value']);
    $position      = get_term_name($profile->field_scout_rank[0]['value']);
    $homephone     = trim($paid_user->home_phone);
    $cellphone     = trim($paid_user->cell_phone);
    $email         = $profile->email_1;
    $paid_status   = 'Paid';
    $payment_date  = date_format_date($paid_user->created_date[0]['value'],$type = 'custom', $format = 'm/d/Y');
    $csv_output .= "\"".$role_name."\"".","."\"".$lname ."\"".","."\"".$firstname."\"".","."\"".$patrol."\"".","."\"".$position."\"".","."\"".$homephone."\"".",".$cellphone.","."\"".$paid_status."\"".","."\"".$payment_date."\""."\r";    
  }

  return $csv_output;
}

function getUnpaidUsers($nid) {
    $csv_output = '';
    $all_unpaid_scout_list = db_query("SELECT * FROM users
                                     INNER JOIN users_roles ON users.uid = users_roles.uid
                                     WHERE users_roles.rid =7
                                     AND users.uid NOT IN (
                                     SELECT attendee_uid FROM signup_event WHERE event_nid = %d)
                                     ORDER BY name ASC",$nid);
    while($unpaid_user = db_fetch_object($all_unpaid_scout_list)){
      $role_name     = 'Scout';
      $profile       = content_profile_load(scout_profile, $unpaid_user->uid);
      $firstname     = $profile->field_sfname[0]['value'];
      $lname         = $profile->field_last_name[0]['value'];
      $patrol        = get_term_name($profile->field_scout_patrol[0]['value']);
      $position      = get_term_name($profile->field_scout_rank[0]['value']);   
      $homephone     = trim($profile->home_phone[0]['value']);
      $cellphone     = trim($profile->cell_phone[0]['value']);
      $email         = $profile->email_1;
      $paid_status   = 'Unpaid';
      $payment_date  = '';
      $csv_output .= "\"".$role_name."\"".","."\"".$lname ."\"".","."\"".$firstname."\"".","."\"".$patrol."\"".","."\"".$position."\"".","."\"".$homephone."\"".",".$cellphone.",".$email.","."\"".$paid_status."\"".","."\"".$payment_date."\""."\r";
    }


    return $csv_output;
}

function event_signup_download_detail($nid)
{ 
    global $user;   
    module_load_include('inc', 'signup_event', 'event_signup_view');
    $csv_output = '';
    $csv_output .= "Role,Last name,First Name,Patrol,Position,Home phone,Cell Phone,Email,Payment Status,Payment Date\n";        

    // add the paid users to the csv 
    $csv_output .= getPaidScoutUsers($nid);

    // get unpaid users, add them to the csv
    $csv_output .= getUnpaidUsers($nid);

    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;   filename=\"Registration_Dues_Information.csv\"");
    print $csv_output;
    exit; 

}
```

note: i didn't test this code

Comment: I got the problem but and it would be better to solve that by splitting them in your way.

Comment: I have made it work and your split function idea did great in that...I am accepting this as answer..
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

```
while($unpaid_user = db_fetch_object($all_unpaid_scout_list)){
      $role_name 1    = 'Scout';
      $profile1       = content_profile_load(scout_profile, $unpaid_user->uid);
      $firstname1     = $profile->field_sfname[0]['value'];
      $lname1         = $profile->field_last_name[0]['value'];
      $patrol1        = get_term_name($profile->field_scout_patrol[0]['value']);
      $position1      = get_term_name($profile->field_scout_rank[0]['value']);   
      $homephone1     = trim($profile->home_phone[0]['value']);
      $cellphone1     = trim($profile->cell_phone[0]['value']);
      $email1         = $profile->email_1;
      $paid_status1   = 'Unpaid';
      $payment_date1  = '';
      $csv_output .= "\"".$role_name1."\"".","."\"".$lname1 ."\"".","."\"".$firstname1."\"".","."\"".$patrol1."\"".","."\"".$position1."\"".","."\"".$homephone1."\"".",".$cellphone1.",".$email1.","."\"".$paid_status1."\"".","."\"".$payment_date1."\""."\r";
    }

echo $csv_output;
```

Simply replace the second while loop with this one.

Comment: What does echo  $csv_output; print?

Comment: @RajeevK can you paste it here?

Comment: I think the problem is something other, like my $nid was not giving result with the query so I changed that & now I have result but still inside while loop where i am trying to fetch the result array, its not returning for something...

Comment: Print $paid_user  inside the while loop and also try to echo and run the query in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Are you getting the value of $profile->field_scout_patrol[0]['value']?

Comment: I have edited the code now, which I am using suggested by Stephen. I tested all the variable value in the while loop in there but it's giving the result only once..

Comment: I have total 55 result from this query but if I echo any variable inside the loop of first function, it gives result only once..though all variable is returning something that is correct..
But when I am trying both function to be called for CSV...page is getting blank

Comment: echo $role_name,$firstname,$lname,$patrol,$position,$homephone,$cellphone,$email,$paid_status;
is returning one result...